# PowerBI DAX - Showing value for one category when another is selected

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop, powerbi-filters

I think I have a basic DAX filter problem that I am stuck with.

I have the following Sales fact table, where PeriodID is always 2:

| Date | Value | Prod | PeriodID |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2022 | 10.00 | Table | 2 |
| 2021 | 10.00 | Table | 2 |
| 2021 | 10.00 | Chair | 2 |

It is joined to the following Period dimension table:

| PeriodID | Description |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Opening |
| 2 | Closing |

In the Matrix visualization, I am hoping to achieve this:

|  | Opening (PeriodID = 1, 2021) | Closing (PeriodID = 2, 2022) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Table | 10.00 | 10.00 |
| Chair | 10.00 | 0.00 |

Since there is no PeriodID = 1 in the fact table, I try to achieve this with a measure for **If PeriodID = 1, show PeriodID = 2 for 2021**

However, Opening does not show up at all.

|  | Closing (PeriodID = 2, 2022) |
| --- | --- |
| Table | 10.00 |

[Current Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SoqQc.png)

Following is my formula:

```
Sales_Total = 

VAR Calculate_Opening = 
CALCULATE(
    SUM(Sales[Value]),
    REMOVEFILTERS(Sales[PeriodID]),
    REMOVEFILTERS(Sales[Date]),
    FILTER(
        Sales,
        Sales[PeriodID] = 1
          &&Sales[Date] = SELECTEDVALUE(Sales[Date])-1
    )
)

VAR Results =
SWITCH(SELECTEDVALUE(Period[PeriodID]),
        1, Calculate_Opening,
        SUM(Sales[Value])
)

Return Results
```

I tried working around different filter functions to no avail, and I am not sure how to proceed debugging this. Any help is really appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: To debug you can breakdown your measure to RETURN the “sub-parts” instead of “Results”. You may also want to look up, how `FILTER ()` works and what it does to the related table. Basically, you filter your **Sales** table against `Sales[PeriodID] = 1` (among others). What outcome can be expected? Good luck!

Comment: Thank you for your attention! I have tried returning subsections of the formula, and I know the date - 1 year is working. I am guessing the "VAR Calculate_Opening" part does not get evaluated at all, since Sales[PeriodID] = 1 does not exist in the Sales table. Do you know if this is true?

Comment: You could try to leave out this line of the filter condition and see what happens.